# Paginating in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, pagination

I am working on an assignment for Uni however I've ran into a snag paginating my comments field. I have put my Controller, Model and View bellow(in that order)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Comment;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CommentController extends Controller
{
    const COMMENTS_PER_PAGE = 5;

    public function index () {
        $comments = Comment::paginate (self::COMMENTS_PER_PAGE);
        return view ('index') -> with (['comments' => $comments]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    public function show(Comment $comment)
    {
        //
    }

    public function edit(Comment $comment)
    {
        //
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Comment $comment)
    {
        //
    }

    public function destroy(Comment $comment)
    {
        //
    }
}

<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{

    public static function paginate(int $COMMENTS_PER_PAGE)
    {
    }
}

{{--@extends('layout.master)--}}
{{--@section('content')--}}
    <div class="container main-table">
        <div class="box">

            <h1 class="title">Guestbook Comments</h1>

            @if (count ($comments) > 0)
                <table class="table is-striped is-hoverable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Comment</th>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Likes</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @foreach ($comments as $c)
{{--declaring the comments--}}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $c -> name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> comment }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> created_at -> format ('D jS F') }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $c -> likes }}</td>
                        </tr>

                    @endforeach

                    </tbody>
                </table>
{{--looking at pagination--}}
                {{ $comments -> links() }}
                        @else
                <div class="notification is-info">
                    <p>
                        The Guestbook is empty. Why not add a comment?
                    </p>
                </div>
            @endif
        </div>

    </div>
{{--@endsection--}}
```

I managed to get it to display the comments before changing to pagination. After doing this I ran into issues getting it to display. I don't get an error I just get a blank page as if nothing is wrong. It doesn't show any of my headings or text that is not from my comments table.

Has anyone got any ideas about why this is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :D

**Update 17:44 13/11/19**

Just realised that the link was going to the wrong page but just now figured out that the count function is having and issue as it says that there is no relevant ARRAY ("Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (View: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\Assignment\resources\views\comment\comments.blade.php) ")

Does anyone know why this is?
I thought it would just list comments 1 by 1 up until it reads out 5 comments.

Any ideas on how to fix this? :)

Answer (score 0):

change  {{ $comments -> links() }} & try this

```
 {!! $comments->render() !!}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply I have tried what you suggested but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to paginate like this.

```
public function index () {
   const COMMENTS_PER_PAGE = 5;
    $comments = Comment::paginate(self::COMMENTS_PER_PAGE);
    return view('index', compact('comments'))
        ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);


}
```

and also, change

{!! $comments->links() !!}
to 
{!! $comments->render() !!}

Comment: I tried what you suggested however I still get the same error as before.

Comment: its silly but why there are empty spaces ?

replace your function with this: 

``` 
 public function index() {
        $comments = Comment::paginate(self::COMMENTS_PER_PAGE);
        return view ('index')->with(['comments' => $comments]);
    } 

```

Answer (score 0):

```
 {!! $comments->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).